# Why do Excel VBA modules become empty?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have many Excel files with VBA macro modules.

For one of such file, the macros didn't run so while investigating I noticed that double clicking on the VBA modules doesn't open any code. Sometimes the file just doesn't open (crashes). My guess is that the file has got corrupted but excel doesn't say so. What could be the issue?

I've found 3 workarounds so far:

1. Repair and open the file
2. Or send it to my colleague who can just open it fine, and when he sends it back to me I can open it fine
3. Or disable macro, recompile the VBAProject, save, enable macro, open file

After either of above workarounds I'm able to open the file and then the macro runs fine, and double clicking on the modules shows me the code.

Comment: Something else must be going wrong. Macro modules are plain text. If they become corrupted, you cannot repair them.

Comment: Is there a checklist to review and identify the cause?

Comment: Not that I know. I just know what macro modules are as I've programmed them extensively.

Comment: I've update the question with more details of workarounds, but unable to understand the root cause. Probably some caching or compile related issue.

Comment: So essentially your macros are being blocked somehow. Check stuff like your virusscanner and don't forget to reboot to get rid of any quirckyness on your system.